# How to detect on what ListView onItemClick was happened?

Tags: android, listview

In `Activity` I have two `ListViews` but now I must to detect on what `ListView` user clicked.
I have added `adapters` and `setOnItemClickListener(this);` for each `ListView`.

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int i, long l) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.list_1:
            Toast.makeText(this, "111111111", 0).show();
            break;
        case R.id.list_2:
            Toast.makeText(this, "222222222", 0).show();
            break;
    }
}
```

But `v.getId()` returns -1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use `a.getId()` instead of `v.getId()`

i mean use `AdapterView<?> a`

```
switch (a.getId()) {
        case R.id.list_1:
            Toast.makeText(this, "111111111", 0).show();
            break;
        case R.id.list_2:
            Toast.makeText(this, "222222222", 0).show();
            break;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

in onCreate(), get references to your listviews:

```
listview1 = findViewById(R.id.list_1);
listview2 = findViewById(R.id.list_2);
```

then, in `onItemClicked()` you can test like this:

```
 if (a == listview1){
       //something
    }
 else if(a==listview2){
      //something
    }
```